# Can anyone explain the rationale behind these rollbacks?

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

There was some very unusual rollback activity today on a question I edited, where out of nowhere a user who wasn't involved in the conversation, answers, etc came in and rolled back a couple different times and introduced some completely extraneous tags to the item, while at the same time completely undoing a lot of IMHO useful formatting for readability fixes I had made.  So I'm curious at others thoughts about this.  I tried to do the right thing here by asking folks on chat what to do and not getting into an edit war and posting here :-) per another meta post I recently read.

[dereferencing this causes Segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183324/dereferencing-this-causes-segmentation-fault)

Being intrigued I took a look at his activity, and found additional "odd" behavior on his last actual activity period, where he undid an OP's edit of the OP's own post.  The OP in that case was Ed Healy (21K+ rep), and this guy has 3kish.  Eventually another mod came by to fix it; but this just doesn't feel right.

[Linux/Unix command to determine if process is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117507/linux-unix-command-to-determine-if-process-is-running/9117577#9117577)

While not definitive or restrictive I also noticed the user in question doesn't have a single tag for any of the topics involved in the case of mine he edited today.  Which combined with everything else struck me (and several people on chat jaif, sehe ) as extremely odd.

Everything else in the user's history looks normal though aside from a huge decrease in activity which is just coincidental and could be for any number of reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start from the [second example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117507/linux-unix-command-to-determine-if-process-is-running/9117577#9117577) which is simple: the user who edited most likely did not notice the editor who changed `pgrep` to `grep` is the answer author, hence thought it's invalid edit. I rolled back again and left a comment.

As for the [first example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183324/dereferencing-this-causes-segmentation-fault), it's matter of tags as far as I can see it. The first non-OP edit (revision 3) suggested a good edit plus adding some tags the editor deemed relevant. The reviewer of the suggested edit clicked "Improve" and removed some of those tags, hence creating new revision - the fourth. Other 2K+ user (yes, same from other example) thought the tags are still not good and added back all the tags from revision 2, then regretted it and taking a guess, he edited to previous revision by mistake instead of fixing the tags manually. 100k user saw the mess and rolled it all back.

Bottom line, nothing fishy as far as I can tell, just chain of innocent mistakes.

Comment: Thanks that's sorta what I/we figured on the chat, just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something bad :-)

Comment: Nope, all  good @UpAndAdam. You did well to report it, cheers! By the way, where did you see moderator stepping in? Couldn't see any moderator in any of the examples.

Comment: maybe it wasn't a moderator, there was a usernumber some sort who did the edits right before your rollback on example two, I assumed it was a mod I guess it wasn't. I keep forgetting very-high rep / trusted users != moderators :-p

Comment: You mean [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TPBs7.png)? It's a deleted user. :)